# IDE and external keyboard on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, programming-languages, hardware

I tried this question in another forums, like OS X hints, so I try it here now. I just wonder if there is somewhere available an external keyboard for the iphone, so I can program on the road. And second question, if you know good IDE's on the iphone for programming and compiling on C++

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you jailbreak your device, it is possible to use a Bluetooth keyboard with it, by virtue of the "BTstack Keyboard" application. There is not, however, a pocket IDE (though you could use MobileTerminal and a text editor.)

Comment: wow, and once jailbroken, any bluetooth keyboard would work using that app?

Comment: Many keyboards already do, and the authour is very receptive to bug reports. There is more information at http://keyboard.ringwald.ch.

Comment: great! and yes, with terminal, i can connect to my unix machine

Comment: Indeed. You can have a full shell (complete with GNU tools and, in fact, a compiler) and access to an ssh client.

Comment: A wild DHowett has appeared! I have the Think Outside Stowaway Bluetooth keyboard and it works great with BTstack